# Deriving the effective potential from the Schwarzschild metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, orbital-motion, geodesics

I am attempting to derive the effective potential for a test particle around a massive object from the Schwarzschild metric; however, an extra term has appeared in my solution compared to Wikipedia's, which I am most confused about. A quick summary of my derivation is below; why is this extra term here, and what is its physical meaning?

**My Method:**
Assuming the particle is on the equatorial plane where $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$, the Schwarzschild metric becomes $$-c^2\mathrm{d}\tau=-\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)c^2\mathrm{d}t^2+\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2\mathrm{d}\theta^2$$
The radial equation is $$\ddot{r}=-\Gamma^1_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu$$
where an overdot represents differentiation with respect to the proper time. The appropriate Christoffel symbols are $$
\begin{matrix}
\Gamma^{1}_{00}=\frac{c^2r_s}{2r^2}\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right) & \Gamma^{1}_{11}=-\frac{r_s}{2r^2}\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1} & \Gamma^1_{22}=-r\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)
\end{matrix}
$$
making the radial equation $$\ddot{r}=-\frac{c^2r_s}{2r^2}\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)\dot{t}^2+\frac{r_s}{2r^2}\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}\dot{r}^2+r\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)\dot{\theta}^2$$
From the metric, we know that $$\dot{t}^2=\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{c^2}\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1}\dot{r}^2+\frac{r^2}{c^2}\dot{\theta}^2\right)$$
Substituting this in, we get $$\ddot{r}=-\frac{c^2r_s}{2r^2}+r\dot{\theta}^2-\frac{3r_s}{2}\dot{\theta}^2$$
Substituting in the definition of angular momentum $\dot{\theta}=\frac{L}{\mu r^2}$, where $\mu$ is the reduced mass, multiplying across by the particle's mass $m$, and substituting in the definition of the Schwarzschild radius $r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$, one finally gets $$m\ddot{r}=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}+\frac{mL^2}{\mu^2 r^3}-\frac{3L^2G(M+m)}{\mu c^2r^4}$$ from which the potential is found to be

$$ \bbox[5px,border:1.5px solid black]
{
U(r)=-\frac{GMm}{r}+\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}+\color{red}{\frac{m}{M}\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}}-\frac{G(M+m)L^2}{r^3\mu c^2}
}
$$

---

Why is the term in red there? It should be very small, so perhaps it is negligible? Is there a fundamental error in my derivation? If this is correct, what is the physical meaning of this term; is it a relativistic correction to the centrifrugal force?

Comment: While I haven't checked the calculations, the appearance of the reduced mass together with both $M$ and $m$ worries me.

Comment: @Javier all three black terms are in Wikipedia's expression for the potential, at least, so the reduced mass with $M$ and $m$ has some precedent.

Comment: something is wrong with this equation $m\,\ddot{r}=...$, I get

$m\,\ddot r=-\frac{a\,L^2}{r^4}+\frac{b\,L^2}{r^3}-\frac{c}{r^2}$

Comment: @Eli it was a typo; thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: sorry but i don't get your equation i get this:

$3\,{\frac {{L}^{2}GM}{{\mu}^{2}{r}^{4}{c}^{2}}}-{\frac {{L}^{2}}{{r}^{
3}{\mu}^{2}}}+{\frac {GM}{{r}^{2}}}+{\ddot{r}}=0
$ ???

Comment: I think that the potential is for a particle with vanishing mass, so the extra term is negligible. @Eli - Using the reduced mass formula $\mu=Mm/(M+m)$ shows your equation is the same.